# Is there anyway to turn off the beginning of turn announcement in civ5?

Tags: civilization-5

At the beginning of every turn a bar appears across the screen announcing the name of your leader, your civ and the year. I dont know why, but this drives me nuts, and I'd love to be able to turn it off, but cant find an option to.

Comment: This happens to you for **every** turn?

Comment: @TZHX This happens for me on every turn, too. Although it hasn't bothered me enough to try to figure out how to turn it off, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official way to remove that "bar". There might be a mod for it though. Look around in the mod browser from the main menu.